# Long startup time for typescript server project

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am facing a very long startup of my nodeJS server project. Basically it is a backend server written in typescript and uses express server.

The command I use to start the server is

nodemon --ignore output/ --exec ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node -- ./src/server.ts

I suspect it is due to compilation of typescript into js, but it is just taking too long, sometimes it takes 5 minutes to start.

Any clue where I should look to troubleshoot?

Comment: How much code do you have? How long does it take? Have you tried measuring the compile time independently by running just the compiler?, Maybe the ts-node spins up the compiler each time and does a complete compilation. Try running the compiler in watch mode (`tsc - - watch` I belive) and executing the Javascript directly instead of going through ts-node.

Comment: Have you try to compile your ts script first and run the node with your js version.